# preg_replace function not removing minus sign anymore

Tags: php

I have been using this function on my page for a while, and suddenly it is not working correctly

```
public function stripSignMinus($money)
{
    return preg_replace('/[^\d-.]+/', '', $money);
}
```

It is supposed to strip out all letter, symbols, and minus sign.

However it is no longer stripping the minus sign.
I have been getting error messages that preg_replace has been deprecated.

I am wondering if it is not removing the minus sign because it is deprecated, and so I tried

```
return preg_replace_callback('/[^\d-.]+/','', $money);
```

However that doesn't work at all. It doesn't remove anything. So I am guessing I am using preg_replace_callback wrong.

I will say that I am not very good with preg_replace expressions.

I need to call it with

```
$functions->stripSignMinus("£-5");
```

replacing what is in quotes and remove the minus sign and the currency symbol. The bove code used to work but no longer works.
Of course the item in quotes can be a string also.

Comment: Escape the `-` like `\-` to avoid it being treated as a range operator

Comment: I tried return preg_replace('/[^\d\-.]+/','', $money); as you suggested, but it is still leaving the minus sign in

Comment: preg_replace_callback() expects a name of a function in its second parameter. more info on: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php. Btw, the preg_replace is not deprecated, only the `/e` modifier is

Comment: If you want to replace everything that is not a digit, why don't you simply: `/[^\d]+/` ?

Comment: leo that does work, but it also removes the decimal point. I need the decimal point to stay in

Comment: @ThomasWilliams Uh, ok, then: `/[^\d\.]+/`

Comment: Thanks Leo. Had to give the upvote to Vitalij though because put his answer as an answer. I am not very good with these preg  expressions. I did try reading about them, but a lot of it went over my head.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what about

```
 function stripSignMinus($money)
{
    return preg_replace('/[^\d\.]+/','',$money);
}
```

https://regex101.com/r/mGuipm/1 here you can test the results

Comment: This only works if I don't have a currency symbol. eg it works if I put -5, but not if I send £-5. I was really wanting the preg_replace to work, as it was working before, and I think a php update killed it.

Comment: ok sorry here a working example



    function stripSignMinus($money)
    {
    return preg_replace('/[^\d\.]+/','',$money);
    }


    var_dump(stripSignMinus('-12322132asdasdasd'));
    var_dump(stripSignMinus('12.10asdasd'));
    var_dump(stripSignMinus('£-5'));

Comment: Thankyou vitalij that works. If you post it as an answer I can upvote you